# Ionic Forms with ngModel

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a form I want to map to an model object. When I add `[[ngModel]]` to the `ion-input`, the page does not load (no errors).

**html**

`<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="personModel.username" formControlName="username" id="username"></ion-input>`

**ts**

```
private personModel: PersonModel = null;
this.personModel = this.navParams.get('personModel');
```

Any ideas why the `[[ngModel]]` is not working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It was my fault. I had the element did not match the model (case match):

```
[(ngModel)]="personModel.username"
```

should be

```
[(ngModel)]="personModel.userName"
```